# How to override AutoSlugField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to override to a record's slug field. In my view I automatically create a new record when add_post page loaded. Like:

```
def add_post(request):
    post=Post(owner=request.user)
    post.save()
    post_id = post.id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = add_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            #other fields

            updated_post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            updated_post.title = form_title
            #save other fields...
            updated_post.save()
```

And I have slug_field in my models.py as:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    #other fields...
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_form='title', unique=True)
```

In my views.py after `post = Post(owner=request.user)`line; it creates a record with a default slug field name because there is no title value yet.

But then, as you see, I updated that post(adding title and other fields). But slug field doesn't update itself. It is still that default slug name.

How can I fix this? If it is not possible I am gonna remove AutoSlugField from my projects and use just post id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From AutoSlugField documentation:

> always_update – boolean: if True, the slug is updated each time the model instance is saved. Use with care because cool URIs don’t change (and the slug is usually a part of object’s URI). Note that even if the field is editable, any manual changes will be lost when this option is activated.

So this should work:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_form='title', always_update=True, unique=True)
```

Comment: This does not work in 2019. 'overwrite=True' is the latest from the github repo. 
https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/fields/__init__.py -  "overwrite: If set to True, overwrites the slug on every save (default: False)"

Answer (score 1):

The Better documentation is the own code:

[http://django-command-extensions.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/django_extensions/db/fields/**init**.py](http://django-command-extensions.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/django_extensions/db/fields/__init__.py)

> slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', overwrite=True,
>   unique=True)

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=500, populate_from='name', null=True, blank=True, always_update=True, unique=True)
```